# Is there a push notifications api for a locations application on flutter

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification

I'm currently working on a flutter navigation application that can enable a user to take pictures of places and store them as familiar locations and has the capacity to inform a user in case they have passed by that specific area for example a new and upcoming restaurant.
My challenge is I do not know how to use push notifications to specifically inform the user upon arriving or passing by their destination

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package

> https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

This package will help you get constant location update of the user and then by using this package calculate distance between the user and the restaurant you want. Fire a local notification using the following package

> https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

when the user passes some distance from your restaurant or when he is about to come close to that restaurant.

Hope this is clear.